# AWS Lambda: Execute function B 10 minutes after function A

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Im developing a serverless backend for a time sensitive application.

Is it possible to execute Lambda function `B` XX minutes after Lambda function `A`?

Im looking for a clean serverless solution. Using `setTimeout` or a similar approach is too much of a hack to be accepted.

**Example:** Send a notification using SNS 10 minutes after a Lambda function has executed.

Comment: You should check out AWS Step Functions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use SQS with a delayed delivery.

1. Lambda-A adds a message to an SQS queue and sets the delivery delay of 10 minutes. You can set any delay between 0 and 15 minutes. You can also use SQS Delay Queues to delay all messages added to the queue.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html
2. After 10 minutes SQS message becomes visible and SQS triggers Lambda-B.
3. Lambda-B receives Amazon SQS Event and deletes message from the queue using receipt handle. Here is an example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sqs:

.

```
 "Records": [
    {
        "messageId": "c80e8021-a70a-42c7-a470-796e1186f753",
        "receiptHandle": "AQEBJQ+/u6NsnT5t8Q/VbVxgdUl4TMKZ5FqhksRdIQvLBhwNvADoBxYSOVeCBXdnS9P+erlTtwEALHsnBXynkfPLH3BOUqmgzP25U8kl8eHzq6RAlzrSOfTO8ox9dcp6GLmW33YjO3zkq5VRYyQlJgLCiAZUpY2D4UQcE5D1Vm8RoKfbE+xtVaOctYeINjaQJ1u3mWx9T7tork3uAlOe1uyFjCWU5aPX/1OHhWCGi2EPPZj6vchNqDOJC/Y2k1gkivqCjz1CZl6FlZ7UVPOx3AMoszPuOYZ+Nuqpx2uCE2MHTtMHD8PVjlsWirt56oUr6JPp9aRGo6bitPIOmi4dX0FmuMKD6u/JnuZCp+AXtJVTmSHS8IXt/twsKU7A+fiMK01NtD5msNgVPoe9JbFtlGwvTQ==",
        "body": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",
        "attributes": {
            "ApproximateReceiveCount": "3",
            "SentTimestamp": "1529104986221",
            "SenderId": "594035263019",
            "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1529104986230"
        },
        "messageAttributes": {},
        "md5OfBody": "9bb58f26192e4ba00f01e2e7b136bbd8",
        "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
        "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:594035263019:NOTFIFOQUEUE",
        "awsRegion": "us-west-2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why max delay is only 15 minutes?

Comment: I have no idea why the maximum delay is 15 minutes. It's a design decision made by AWS engineers, I'm sure they had their reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that using [SQS Delay Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) to trigger lambda B.

Steps as follows

Create an SQS queue with message delay set to 10 minutes
Set Lambda B trigger as the above SQS
Now after Lambda function A executes put a message on SQS

Now because there is a delay set on SQS the message will be available after 10 minutes and once it is available it will trigger Lambda B

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve what you're looking for using [message timers in SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message-with-timer.html).

Function A should publish a message to a queue with a 10 minute delay on it and Function B should subscribe to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do that is with AWS Step Functions.
You can either -

1. Configure a step machine composed of function A, a wait state, function B.
2. Invoke a step machine from function A, that will be composed of a wait state and function B (if you want to have a delay from the beginning of function A).

Comment: Can you cancel a step function or modify the time?

Comment: In step functions, you can use the output of one step as an input to another. If a step is currently running you can't cancel it (but you should not need to do that). Regarding the wait time - "You can choose either a relative time, specified in seconds from when the state begins, or an absolute end-time, specified as a timestamp." (taken from [AWS docs]  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html)). The duration can depend on the state's input.